# VIM - different colorschemes for different file types

Tags: vim, ide, color-scheme

I would like to configure my Vim as an IDE for Python and C/C++.

I know that .vimrc file has to be expanded, but what are commands to create one colorscheme for .py files and another one for .c files? Files without these extensions should work in "regular" Vim style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an autocmd the file type to do this.

```
" Set 'foo' colorscheme for Python files
autocmd Filetype python colorscheme foo

" Set 'bar' colorscheme for C/C++ files
autocmd Filetype c colorscheme bar
autocmd Filetype cpp colorscheme bar
```

Caveat: as has been discussed in the comments, color scheme is global in Vim. I believe this is true for console Vim and for GUI Vim. So this is of limited utility unless you tend to only use console Vim and you only edit one file at a time (or one type of file at a time).

That is, if you open a Python file, it will set the color scheme. If you then open a C file in another window (in the same Vim instance), it will set the color scheme again - but this affects *everything*, including your Python window and any other windows you might have open in Vim.

Comment: What colorscheme will be used if I open Python and C files in different windows? (Hint: the last one for both windows. Colorschemas are global.)

Comment: @phd I suppose it depends on what the user is actually using - in the case of console Vim, windows aren't supported (though multiple open files are). In a GUI such as MacVim, yes, you'd end up with that problem.

Comment: @DanLowe Of course does console Vim support windows; e.g. via `<C-W>s` or `:split`! The differences between terminal and GUI version are intentionally small.